# How to create Floating bubble/Floating ball in android

Tags: android, android-studio, floating-action-button, screen-recording

I'm working on developing a screen recording feature for my Android application and I want to incorporate a floating controls bubble similar to the one seen in XRecorder (linked image for reference: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfBgs.jpg). I've attempted to use the Floating-Bubble-View library (https://github.com/TorryDo/Floating-Bubble-View), but encountered several issues, particularly when expanding the bubble.

My goal is to create a stable and reliable floating controls bubble that allows users to initiate and control screen recordings seamlessly. However, I'm facing challenges in achieving this functionality without encountering performance issues or glitches.

Could someone provide guidance or suggest alternative libraries or approaches to implement such a floating controls bubble effectively? Additionally, any insights or best practices for handling screen recording functionalities within a floating bubble interface would be highly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!